# When to use *args , *kwargs in python and django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I would like to clarify the following confusion for python and also for django. I understand that you use args when you are not sure how many non-keyword arguments you have and you use kwargs when you are not sure how many keyword arguments you have.

However, I am having some confusion as to when to write args and kwargs and when to use something like a keyword eg slug in my views.py in django and for python functions in general.

Take for example:

`def home_page(request, *args, *kwargs):`

`def login_page(request, username):`

Why can't I use:
`def login_page(request, *args, *kwargs):`
Wouldn't it be better that I use `*args, *kwargs` instead of `username` since I wont limit myself to the number of variables I can have in my view?

Does it have something to do with the URLs too? I understand that if it is `(request, username)` in views.py, my urls.py will need to have a `/login/<username>`, so if it is `*args, *kwargs`, what should it be?

Comment: Why would you use a flexible number of arguments in your function `login_page`? What are you going to do with those extra parameters? If you don't need them, you don't need `*args` and `*kwargs`. I'm not even sure why they are used in `home_page`.

Comment: What's wrong with using `*args, *kwargs` even though I don't need those extra parameters? So could you share an example where I would need to use `*args, *kwargs`

Comment: Also if I use `*args, *kwargs`, does my urls.py need to anything else apart from the name or just eg /home/

Comment: What do you gain from it? If you use this approach you might call the function with a lot of extra parameters that don't do anything. And why would you do that? The reason might well be, that you made an error and wanted to call an other function. Be explicit.

Comment: Heres why I think i will gain from it, correct me if I am wrong pls. Eg: `def hello(request, *args, *kwargs)' then I can do eg `account = Account.objects.get(id=id)` and also `blog = Blog.objects.get(slug=slug)`

Comment: If I only use `def hello(request, username): ` and I try `blog = Blog.objects.get(slug=slug)` they will tell me slug is not defined

Comment: but because since I'm already using `*args, *kwargs`, will i still get the error since I kind of already specified the keyword

Comment: Bro sorry if i dont make sense, I just want to clearly differentiate under what kind of scenarios I need to use `*args, *kwargs` and what kind of scenarios i need to just use eg `(request,slug)` and also if I use `*args, *kwargs` how will my url look like

Comment: The proper "syntax" is `**kwargs`, with two asterisks. Then, `**kwargs` is akin to a `dict`. So, to extract values from it, you have to do something like `slug = kwargs['slug']`. You use this variable arguments syntax for variadic functions, i.e., when you know you will get a variable number of arguments, don't know in advance how many, but need them all. There are other scenarios, such as dynamic method invocation, and subclass constructors calling `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)`, ie, passing parameters to the superclass constructor.

Comment: Would recommend reading: [link](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/)

Comment: thanks for your help bro! @Philippe I will check out the link! If possible, do you mind sharing your email so when I post another question about this I can notify you :) Also, from your answer, I can deduce that we hardly would need to use `*args, *kwargs` in django